# Ordering items in a block that have been pulled out of a join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is the block. `Group` and `Workout` are models connected with a `has_many :through` relationship and a `GroupsWorkout` join model in between.

```
<% @group.workouts.each do |workout| %>
    <%= link_to workout.name, workout %><br />
<% end %>
```

I want to order `workout.name` by the `workout_order` column in the `WorkoutsGroup` table

normally I would just use `Model.order(column_name, DESC)` but as far as I can tell, that doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order the items just in the page before displaying them, then you can sort the workouts collection before iterating like so:

```
<% @group.workouts.sort_by{|workout| workout.workout_order}.each do |workout| %>
  <%= link_to workout.name, workout %><br />
<% end %>
```

Edit: ah, I think I misunderstood your question. Give me a moment to refine the answer.

You can order your workouts by a column in the join table by defining the order in the association like so:

Group model:

```
has_many :workouts, :through => :group_workouts, :order => "workoutorder DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add order in the `Group` model:

```
has_many : workouts, :through => :group_workouts, :order => 'workouts.name'
```